# Why was exception not caught within the closure?

Tags: c#, exception, lambda

Here is the code example:

```
    public IList<LogEntry> ReadLogs(Guid id, string name)
    {
        var logs = this.RetrieveLogs(id, name);

        if (logs != null)
        {
            foreach (LogEvent logEvent in logs)
            {
                // bla, bla, bla
            }
        }

        return logEntries;
    }

    private IEnumerable<LogEvent> RetrieveLogs(Guid id, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            FilterCriteria filterCriteria = CreateFilterCriteria();
            return (from log in this.loggingProvider.ReadLogs(filterCriteria, 1)
                    where log.ParticipantObjects[0].ParticipantObjectId ==  id.ToString() 
                     && log.LogEventParameters[0].Value == name
                    orderby log.Timestamp.ToLocalTime() descending
                    select log).AsEnumerable();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.tracer.Write(Category.Error, ex, "Error");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now, if there was an exception inside of `loggingProvider.ReadLogs()` method, it will be caught and traced. But if, for example, there is no `ParticipantObjects[0]`, this exception won't be caught and traced here. It seems that it has something to do with lambda expressions and closures.

What is the explanation?

Comment: a query isn't run until you do something with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`loggingProvider.ReadLogs` is executed inside `RetrieveLogs`. But all the other lambdas are executed only when you iterate over them in the outer `this.ReadLogs`.

So the exception is thrown in your upper method, and so cannot be catched inside `RetrieveLogs`.

To avoid this, change `AsEnumerable` to `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to ensure the query is actually executed before returning.

Answer (score 15):

I have said it before and I will undoubtedly say it again:  **the most important thing to know about a query is that a query is a question, not the answer to the question**.

The query object you've built does not execute merely by building it. You are building the question. The question does not actually get *asked* and *answered* until you execute the query. And the execution is outside the try block.

Comment: Since you already assumed what happened, let me just comment that I did not build or execute the query, I was merely analysing somebody's else (here is much simplified) code which produced a bug. Although I knew already what you have here stated, I simply did not notice it was AsEnumerable in the end of the statement, instead of ToList and for some reason, I assumed that was some wierd optimisation involving closures.

Comment: @NenadDobrilovic: Well then, mentally substitute "somebody else" for "you" in the second paragraph. I'm glad you figured out your error -- not noticing that the query was not executed -- and are therefore less likely to make it in the future, and I'm glad you figured out where the logic error in the code is, if in fact there is one.

Answer (score 3):

An `IEnumerable` result from a LINQ query is only evaluated when it is enumerated.

In order for the `Exception` to be thrown where you expect, you need to enumerate the LINQ query result `IEnumerable` using one of the relevant extension methods like `ToList()`.

As a side-note (borrowing from Rene Vogt) you could avoid the `Exception` being thrown by writing your LINQ as follows:

```
return this.loggingProvider.ReadLogs(filterCriteria, 1).Where(log => 
    log.ParticipantObjects.FirstOrDefault() != null &&
    log.ParticipantObjects[0].ParticipantObjectId == id.ToString() &&
    log.LogEventParameters[0].Value == name).OrderBy(log => 
    log.Timestamp.ToLocalTime()).ToList();
```

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. I just wrote it that way because it makes it easier for me to read than the query language. I think the result is the same as long as you don't change `AsEnumerable()` to something that _executes_ the query like `ToList()` or `ToArray()`.

Comment: It is indeed easier. My point is the extra condition would never generate the `NullReferenceException` or `IndexOutOfRangeException` due to checking that `ParticipantObjects[0]` exists.

Comment: So you may want to change `log.ParticipantObjects.First() != null` to `log.ParticipantObjects.FirstOrDefault() != null`, because `First` throws if the selection is empty ;)

Comment: This is simplified version of the production code. I was just analysing the stack trace and noticed that query was executed within foreach loop and did not realise that the method, despite its name, was returning only a query but not the logs themselves. No changes will be done here, as it expected to have an exception if there is no ParticipantObjects[0] in the database.